# PYTHON - recursive function of finding index of variables in multiple layers of lists

Tags: python, list, recursion

I'm trying to make a function that tries to find a variable in multiple (unspecified amount) of layers of lists.

for example:

if a list is something like : `['a',3,'c',['e',['z',6],['r',8,'t']],'z']` and want to find the index of `6`
I would get : `[3][1][1]`

if a list is something like : `[1,2,[3,4],5]` and want to find the index of `3`
I would get : `[2][0]`

I would be happy if somebody helped me with this thing, been trying for 3 days...
(new at coding)

Comment: as a hint, i will suggest to use stack as one of containers

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The second example should be 2/0.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, here is a simple recursive function to find the first matching element:

```
l = ['a',3,'c',['e',['z',6],['r',8,'t']],'z']

def find(l, item):
    for i,e in enumerate(l):
        if isinstance(e, list):
            if (out:=find(e, item)): # python ≥ 3.8, below split in two lines
                return [i, *out]
        elif e == item:
            return [i]
```

Example:

```
find(l, 6)
[3, 1, 1]

find([1,2,[3,4],5], 3)
[2, 0]

find(l, 'missing') # no output
```

Comment: of course it is true, but you should also consider time complexity

Comment: @Egor do you want to elaborate?

Comment: @Timus fair enough, I assumed the object was present, and fixed ;)

Answer (score 0):

i found the discussion very interesting and that's why I've tried to come up with my solution, which is almost the same as this from @mozway, but not using the *:=* operator, which was new to me:

My solution would be :

```
from collections.abc import Iterable

def flatten(items, to_find):
    for num, x in enumerate(items):
        if isinstance(x, Iterable) and not isinstance(x, str):
            return [num, *flatten(x, to_find)]
        elif x == to_find:
            return [num]
```

The result would be as expected : *[3,1,1]*

Here comes the interesting part, although the construction is very similar, I'm almost x2 times slower then the previous solution. Unfortunately I can't spot the reason why and would be glad if someone put some light on the problem :

```
python -m timeit -s"from flat import find" "t = ['a',3,'c',['e',['z',6],['r',8,'t']],'z']" "find(t,6)"
100000 loops, best of 5: 2.87 usec per loop

python -m timeit -s"from flat import flatten" "t = ['a',3,'c',['e',['z',6],['r',8,'t']],'z']" "flatten(t,6)"

50000 loops, best of 5: 5.8 usec per loop
```

The output of the compiler hints that I'm doing more operations then the *find(..)*, but as i said can't "see" it.

My first try was to change the line, but the result is similar

*if isinstance(x, Iterable) and not isinstance(x, str):*
with
*if isinstance(x, list):, but the result is similar:*

```
python -m timeit -s"from flat import flatten2" "t = ['a',3,'c',['e',['z',6],['r',8,'t']],'z']" "flatten2(t,6)"
50000 loops, best of 5: 4.38 usec per loop
```

Thank you in advance :)